# How to transform a number that is counting up to HH:MM:SS?

Tags: javascript

I am counting up values on dynamically generated divs:

```
<div class="count">285489</div>
<div class="count">258569</div>
<div class="count">263548</div>
<div class="count">245856</div>
```

```
setInterval(function(){

    $(".count").each(function() {
        let el = $(this);
        let time = Number(el.text()) + 1;
        el.text(time);
    });

}, 1000);
```

I want to transform those number into a HH:MM:SS format.
I have found the following snippet to achieve this:

```
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}
```

I modified the setInterval() function to use this function above

```
setInterval(function(){

    $(".prod").each(function() {
        let el = $(this);
        let time = Number(el.text()) + 1;
        time = time.toString();
        el.text(time.toHHMMSS());
    });

}, 1000);
```

However, when I run it, the values are incremented by only one second. After the increment, the values are showing NaN:NaN:NaN.

I don't understand. Why is it showing NaN when there should always be the new value available inside the div when it next gets incremented?

`setInterval()` is fired inside my Ajax complete function

All I need is those values to be displayed as HH:MM:SS instead of just a plain number.

Could anybody help?

Comment: after your first run you have entered in colons so your next interval will produce NaNs so you will need to replace them when you try do Number - `Number(el.text().replace(/:/g, ''))`

Comment: @Pete HHMMSS uses base 60. You can't just `+ 1`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I never said just +1, I said the NaN error was caused by the OPs colons and trying to do Number on that, whether the rest of the code works or not I have not commented on - that's why I left a comment and not an answer.  Please read my comment more carefully before having a go at me next time

Comment: @Pete Please accept my excuses if you felt criticised, that was far from my intention. You suggested a fix in the text-to-number part of the code that comes right before `+ 1`, thus my clarification. I've even realised there's already an answer proposing exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that after it performs once, the element text value is no longer numeric, but in your time format.
Try something like this:

```
<div class="count" data-time="285489"></div>
```

So the variable isn't changed when you set text. Then you can use it like this:

```
$(".prod").each(function() {
    let el = $(this);
    let time = Number(el.data("time")) + 1;
    el.data("time", time);
    time = time.toString();
    el.text(time.toHHMMSS());
});
```

That may not be a complete solution, but you get the idea. After setting text now, the time will still be accessible in original format.

Comment: Thank you, sir. That was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

After the first call to `.toHHMMSS`, all the div text become `HH:MM:SS` formatted. On the next iteration of `.setInterval`, we're attempting to parse an `HH:MM:SS` formatted string as an int, which fails and produces a `NaN` (because it's Not a Number). To fix this issue, you have two options:

1. Write a function to translate `HH:MM:SS` back to seconds, and then increment and run `.toHHMMSS` on that.

```
String.prototype.fromHHMMSS = function () {
    if (isNaN(this)) {
        var timeStrArr = this.split(":");
        var hours   = Integer.parseInt(timeStrArr[0]);
        var minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeStrArr[1]);
        var seconds = Integer.parseInt(timeStrArr[2]);
        var totalSeconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds

        return totalSeconds;
    } else {
        return Number(this);
    }
}
```

```
setInterval(function(){

    $(".prod").each(function() {
        let el = $(this);
        let time = el.text().fromHHMMSS() + 1;
        time = time.toString();
        el.text(time.toHHMMSS());
    });

}, 1000);
```

2. Work directly on the `HH:MM:SS` formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Modify below code in for each,

```
let txt = el.text();
if(txt.indexOf(':')){
   txt = txt.replace(/:/g,'')
}     
let time = Number(txt) + 1;
```

Comment: Er... Are you sure? `Number("10:10:59".replace(/:/g,'')) + 1` produces `101060`. That's neither HH:MM:SS time nor a second count.

Answer (score 0):

When code runs for the first time it replaces the original numbers with the HHMMSS representation. You need to either convert from HHMMSS to seconds or, just simpler, store the seconds. Also, having `toHHMMSS()` as method of the `String` object actually makes it harder to use in this case.

I'm storing seconds as properties of the DOM node for simplicity but of course you can use any storage you want.

```js
function toHHMMSS(sec_num) {
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}

let $count = $(".count");
$count.each(function() {
    let el = $(this);
    this.time = Number(el.text());
});
setInterval(function(){
    $count.each(function() {
        let el = $(this);
        let time = ++this.time;
        el.text(toHHMMSS(time));
    });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="count">285489</div>
<div class="count">258569</div>
<div class="count">263548</div>
<div class="count">245856</div>
```